# Error al intentar acceder a los atributos de una clase

Tags: php, mysql

Les comento mi inconveniente:
En mis códigos tengo Las clases: Persona , Cliente, Empleado. Cliente y Empleado extienden de Persona.
Mi inconveniente es cuando quiero crear un cliente porque tengo que acceder a los datos del objeto Persona y al momento de hacerlo me da error. Lo estoy tratando de realizar directamente con conexiones a la base de datos.
Les dejo los códigos y aguardo sus respuestas gracias.

```
<?php

class Persona {

    private $cuit;
    private $name;
    private $surname;
    private $dni;
    private $birthdate;


    private $pdo;

    function __construct($cuit,$pdo){

        $this->pdo = $pdo;

        //La variable $stmt es una consulta ala DB
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM personas WHERE cuit = $cuit");


        //Se ejecuta dicha consulta
        $stmt->execute();

        //Se crea una varialbe que es un array del tipo Persona con las propiedades de dicho objeto
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        //Sele asigna a cada propiedad su valor correspondiente
        $this->cuit = $result['cuit'];
        $this->name = $result['name'];
        $this->surname = $result['surname'];
        $this->dni = $result['dni'];
        $this->birthdate = $result['birthdate'];


        //Cierro la conexion ya que no accedo mas a la trabla de la DB
        $this->pdo=null;


    }

    //########## GETERS #############

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getSurname(){
        return $this->surname;
    }

    public function getDni(){
        return $this->dni;
    }

    public function getCuit(){
        return $this->cuit;
    }

    public function getBirthdate(){
        return $this->birthdate;
    }



    //######## SETERS ################


        public function setName($name){
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function setSurname($surname){
        $this->surname = $surname;
    }

    public function setDni($dni){
        $this->dni = $dni;
    }

    public function setCuit($cuit){
        $this->cuit = $cuit;
    }

    public function setBirthdate($birthdate){
        $this->birthdate = $birthdate;
    }


    //########  Metodos  ##############

    public function getInformation(){

        return '<h2>Datos Personales: </h2>'.
                '<em>Nombre: </em>'.$this->name . '<br>'.
                '<em>Apellido: </em>'. $this->surname . '<br>' .
                '<em>DNI: </em>'. $this->dni .'<br>'.
                '<em>CUIT: </em>'.$this->cuit.'<br>'.
                '<em>Fecha de nacimiento </em>'.$this->birthdate.'<br>';

    }




}

<?php

class Cliente extends Persona {

    private $numbre_client;
    private $email;
    private $phone_personal;
    private $celular;
    private $address;
    private $user;

    private $pdo;
    /*##############Falta la conexion con la base de datos ##################*/
    public function __construct($cuit,$name,$surname,$dni,$birthdate,$user,$pdo)
        {
            $this->pdo = $pdo;
            $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE $user");
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            parent::__construct($name,$surname,$dni,$cuit,$birthdate);
            $this->number_client = $result['number_client'];
            $this->email = $result['email'];
            $this->phone_personal = $result['phone_personal'];
            $this->celular = $result['celular'];
            $this->address = $result['addres'];
            $this->user = $result['user'];
        }


    //############# Geters #####################
    public function getNumberClient(){

        return $this->number_client;
    }

    public function getEmail(){

        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getPhonePersonal(){

        return $this->phone_personal;
    }

    public function getCelular(){

        return $this->celular;
    }
    //Crear clase para mejorar 
    public function getAddress(){

        return $this->address;

    }
    //Es necesario crear la clase usuario y mejorar
    public function getUser(){

        return $this->user;
    }

    //########## Seters ######################
    public function setNumberClient($number){
        $this->number_client = $number;
    }

    public function setEmail($email){
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    public function setPhonePersonal($numero){
        $this->phone_personal = $numero;
    }

    public function setCelular($number){
        $this->celular = $number;
    }
    //Crear clase para mejorar 
    public function setAddress($address){
        $this->address = $address;
    }
    //Es necesario crear la clase usuario y mejorar
    public function setUser($user){
        $this->user = $user;
    }


    //######## Funciones ################
    //Obtiene datos de la clase cliente y de la clase padre
    public function getInformation(){


        return parent::getInformation()
        .'<strong>Numero de cliente: </strong>'. $this->number_client.'<br>'.
        '<strong>Email </strong>'.$this->email . '<br>'.
        '<strong>Telefono Personal: </strong>'. $this->phone_personal.'<br>'.
        '<strong>Celular: </strong>'. $this->celular . '<br>'.
        '<strong>Dirección: </strong>'. $this->address.'<br>'.
        '<strong>User: </strong>'. $this->user.'<br>';
    }

}

<?php

/**
 * 
 */

private $legajo;
private $fecha_de_ingreso;
private $cargo;
private $estudios;
private $nivel_sistema;



class Empleado extends Persona
{
    /*##############Falta la conexion con la base de datos*/
    public function __construct($name,$surname,$dni,$cuit,$birthdate,$legajo,$fecha_de_ingreso,$cargo,$estudios,$nivel_sistema)
    {
        parent::__construct($name,$surname,$dni,$cuit,$birthdate);
        $this->legajo = $legajo;
        $this->fecha_de_ingreso = $fecha_de_ingreso;
        $this->cargo = $cargo;
        $this->estudios = $estudios;
        $this->nivel_sistema = $nivel_sistema;
    }



    //########## Geters ###############

    public function getLegajo()
    {
        return $this->legajo;
    }
    public function getIngreso()
    {
        return $this->fecha_de_ingreso;
    }
    public function getCargo()
    {
        return $this->cargo;
    }
    public function getEstudios()
    {
        return $this->estudios;
    }
    public function getNivelSistema()
    {
        return $this->nivel_sistema;
    }


    //######### Seters ###########

    public function setLegajo($legajo)
    {
        $this->legajo = $legajo;
    }

    public function setIngreso($fecha_de_ingreso)
    {
        $this->fecha_de_ingreso = $fecha_de_ingreso;
    }

    public function setCargo($cargo)
    {
        $this->cargo = $cargo;
    }

    public function setEstudios($estudios)
    {
        $this->estudios = $estudios;
    }

    public function setNivelSistema($nivel_sistema)
    {
        $this->nivel_sistema = $nivel_sistema;
    }
}

?>
```

Acá  instancio el objeto persona con exito y luego al crear el cliente ,que necesita de los atributos de la clase padre al momento de colocarlos en el constructor me da error.

```
<?php
include_once 'Conexion.php';

$conexion = new Conexion();
$pdo = $conexion->pdo;
//modificar la consulta sql capaz se puede hacer en una sola linea
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT cuit FROM personas");
$stmt2 = $pdo->query("SELECT user FROM clientes");//Probar si sirven las comillas simples






    while ($campos=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) && $campos2=$stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    {

        $persona = new Persona($campos['cuit'],$conexion->pdo);

        $cliente = new Cliente($persona['cuit'],$persona['name'],$persona['surname'],$persona['dni'],$persona['birthdate'],$campos2['user'],$conexion->pdo);


    }
?>
```

Y aca Los quiero imprimir en pantalla

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <?php echo $persona->getNumberClient();?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php echo $persona->getEmail();?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php echo $persona->getPhonePersonal();?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php echo $persona->getCelular();?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php echo $persona->getAddress();?>
  </td>
  <td>
    <?php echo $persona->getUser();?>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Veo un error de tipeo en tu constructor de la Clase Cliente, declaras `private $numbre_client;`, creo que escribes mal `numbre` y debe ser `number`, dime si ese es el problema. Saludos

Comment: Hola Mauricio dale me fijo voy probar y te digo. Gracias por la rápida respuesta

Comment: En la pagina donde hago la prueba me sale este error:                                                             Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Persona as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\tienda\ReporteClientes.php:24 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\tienda\Index.php(63): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tienda\ReporteClientes.php on line 24

Comment: Hay que ver el código de ese archivo. Para ver que pone en la línea que te da el error.

Comment: Buenas Mauricio, esta en el post. Esta arriba del <tr>. Es la ultima linea         $cliente = new Cliente($persona['cuit'],$persona['name'],$persona['surname'],$persona['dni'],$persona['birthdate'],$campos2['user'],$conexion->pdo);

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

En la declaración que realizas `$persona = new Persona(...)`, estás asignando a la variable `$persona` un tipo Objecto. Luego en tu siguiente línea tratas dicho Objeto como un Array, lo cual causa el error.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para corregir este problema debes usar el operador apropiado para acceder a las propiedades de un Objeto. Por lo tanto debes corregir tu código para que luzca así:

```
$cliente = new Cliente($persona->cuit, $persona->name, $persona->surname, $persona->dni, $persona->birthdate, $campos2['user'], $conexion->pdo);
```

Con esto el error que mencionas en tu comentario debe estar subsanado.

Saludos.

Comment: Dale lo voy a probar gracias Mauricio...

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente quiero darte la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Luego quiero decirte que al ver tu código se puede apreciar que estás montando un lío tremendo en él por varios motivos que intentaré explicar lo más claramente posible:

- Se ve que intentaste un modelo de datos bien enfocado en cuanto a las relaciones entre las clases. Hay una clase `Persona` y dos clases que extienden de ella, que son `Cliente` y `Empleado`. Eso es correcto, porque una `Persona`  puede ser tanto un `Cliente` como un `Empleado`.
- Pero luego, la lógica que aplicas dentro de las clases no corresponde a la realidad. La lógica es muy sencilla. La clase `Persona` tendrá los miembros que le son propios. `Cliente` y `Empleado`, que **extienden de `Persona`** tendrán los miembros que les son propios declarados, **pero recibirá en el constructor también los miembros que serían propios de `Persona` y se los pasará mediante `parent::__construct()`**
- Cada clase tendrá los *getter*  y *setter*  de sus propios miembros. Y las clases hijas podrán acceder a los de `Persona`. Eso lo tienes bien...

Ahí terminó el modelo de datos. **No necesita nada mas**. Para no cometer errores en la POO, piensa siempre tus clases como un molde, o como una entidad. Digo esto porque estás cometiendo un error gravísimo que es lo que te está causando los problemas actuales.

Reflexionemos, aterrizando en la realidad. ¿Qué es **lo propio** de una `Persona`, o más bién, **de toda** `Persona`?

- El nombre: sí
- El apellido: sí
- La fecha de nacimiento: sí
- ... más cosas propias de **TODA** persona: sí, sí, sí ...
- Una **conexión a la base de datos** : nooooooo
- Hacer consultas a una tabla de la base de datos: no, no y noooo

Entonces, muy sencillo, saca fuera de tus clases todo lo que no sea propio de ellas.

Tú me dirás: *es que necesito la conexión a la base de datos* porque los datos de la persona vienen de una tabla de la base de datos. Eso es legítimo, pero quedamos en que una base de datos no es **propio de una `Persona`**, nadie nace con una base de datos, y puede haber contextos en que necesites usar tu clase sin nada que ver con la base de datos.

> Es más, PDO tiene en su método `fetch` un estilo `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`
>   para mapear resultados a clases <sup>1</sup>. O sea, que haces la
>   consulta, obtienes los datos y los mapeas con una sola línea de código
>   a una clase cualquiera... ¡justo lo que intentas hacer aquí, a mano y
>   penosamente!
>
> ```
>     $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
>
>     //Sele asigna a cada propiedad su valor correspondiente
>     $this->cuit = $result['cuit'];
>     $this->name = $result['name'];
>     $this->surname = $result['surname'];
>     $this->dni = $result['dni'];
>     $this->birthdate = $result['birthdate'];
> ```

Por tanto, hacer manejos como obtención de datos dentro de una clase es algo absurdo. Una clase es como un molde con el que puedes fabricar infinidad de piezas. Al molde le echas el material (miembros de la clase) y luego lo metes al horno para que la pieza se haga. Si aquí el horno es la conexión a la base de datos y las consultas SQL, lo que estás intentando hacer es meter el horno en el molde, cuando debería ser al revés.

O sea, modela tus clases y luego gestiona la conexión aparte (en otra clase si quieres), obtén los datos y luego *informa* a la clase con esos datos.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo simple de las clases bien modeladas. Teniéndolas así, podrías hacer algo tan simple como esto:

1. Crear instancia de la clase
2. Lanzar una consulta (desde fuera de la clase, no desde dentro de ella)
3. Usar `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` para usar los resultados de la consulta como *ingredientes* del pastel

El modelado correcto sería este. He ahorrado casi todos los getter y setter por brevedad. Creo que eso lo tienes claro:

#### `Persona`

```
class Persona {

    private $cuit;
    private $name;
    private $surname;
    private $dni;
    private $birthdate;

    public function __construct($cuit,$name,$surname,$dni,$birthdate)
    {
        $this->cuit=$cuit;
        $this->name=$name;
        $this->surname=$surname;
        $this->dni=$dni;
        $this->birthdate=$birthdate;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

---

#### `Cliente`

```
class Cliente extends Persona {

    private $number_client;
    private $email;
    private $phone_personal;
    private $celular;
    private $address;
    private $user;


    public function __construct($cuit,$name,$surname,$dni,$birthdate,$number_client,$email,$phone_personal,$celular,$address,$user)
        {
            parent::__construct($cuit,$name,$surname,$dni,$birthdate);
            $this->number_client = $number_client;
            $this->email = $email;
            $this->phone_personal = $phone_personal;
            $this->celular = $celular;
            $this->address = $address;
            $this->user = $user;
        }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

}
```

---

#### `Empleado`

```
class Empleado extends Persona
{
    public function __construct($cuit,$name,$surname,$dni,$birthdate,$legajo,$fecha_de_ingreso,$cargo,$estudios,$nivel_sistema)
    {
        parent::__construct($cuit,$name,$surname,$dni,$birthdate);
        $this->legajo = $legajo;
        $this->fecha_de_ingreso = $fecha_de_ingreso;
        $this->cargo = $cargo;
        $this->estudios = $estudios;
        $this->nivel_sistema = $nivel_sistema;
    }

    public function getCargo()
    {
        return $this->cargo;
    }  

}
```

Ten en cuenta siempre esta norma en POO: no metas elementos extraños dentro del modelo de datos, imagina tu modelo de datos como la realidad misma.

Aquí te dejo una <kbd>**[DEMO](https://rextester.com/IPN99672)**</kbd>  del código por si quieres hacer pruebas sobre él.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

---

#### Notas:

---

1. Me refiero a esto, [lo puedes ver en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php):

> `PDO::FETCH_CLASS`: devuelve una nueva instancia de la clase
>   solicitada, haciendo corresponder las columnas del conjunto de
>   resultados con los nombres de las propiedades de la clase, y llamando
>   al constructor después, a menos que también se proporcione
>   `PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE`. Si fetch_style incluye `PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE`
>   (por ejemplo, `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` | `PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE`), entonces
>   el nombre de la clase se determina a partir del valor de la primera
>   columna.

Comment: Me encantó tu respuesta la voy a leer detenidamente muchísimas gracias. Voy a modificar el código y les aviso. Buen comienzo de semana